# Setting cache control on Apache 2.4

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, caching

My site is hosted on Apache 2.4
I try to meet Google Insights recommendations, but I keep getting this recommendation

**Leverage browser caching
Setting an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers for static resources instructs the browser to load previously downloaded resources from local disk rather than over the network.
Leverage browser caching for the following cacheable resources:
    https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js (2 hours)**

In my .htaccess file I added

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # WEEK
    <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
    </FilesMatch>

    # WEEK
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|swf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

However, this did not help at all. In my index.php I tried setting

```
<?php
header( 'Cache-Control: max-age=604800' );
?>
```

No result. My whole .htaccess file is:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On
# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
ErrorDocument 400 /400.php
ErrorDocument 401 /401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /500.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you can do to affect offsite resources. Google will often flag things that you can not control. It will also often be Google resources.

```
https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js
```

That is clearly not on your server and thus you can not change any of it's headers. Don't worry too much about getting a perfect score on PageSpeed. Only worry about those things you can control.

Comment: I thought the idea is to set Cache-Control on my side? It seems I am wrong? P.S. I'm not worried, my SEO is :D

Comment: @Dimentica You do set it for your side. But only for things coming from your server. You can't set it for other sites or for resources referenced by your site. Cache-Control is a header attached to each file as it gets delivered from the server to the client. The client never requests `analytics.js` from your server, because the host is Google.

Comment: I get the point now :) this is why people try to trick Google about that. Thanks!